# Launching Google Tasks standalone in separate window

Tags: google-chrome, google-tasks

How do I launch Google Task manager in a separate window standalone with no tabs and no menus in Windows

Comment: I closed this question because it doesn't meet the [current quality standards](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/quality-standards-error). Related: [Should I vote to close old questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/194116/289691) , [As a mod when should I vote to close content that is not flagged?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/124097/289691). P.S. Self-answered questions are encouraged but the question still should meed the quality standards.

Comment: Martin this question isn't about web applications it is about Chrome browser / operative system and should be on [su].

Answer (score 1):

This can be done using a standard windows short cut.  Create a desktop shortcut to Chrome then change the “target” for this string

"C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --user-data-dir=c:\tmp\scratch\sessionTasks   --new-window "%1" --window-position=10,10 --window-size=500,900 --app=”https://tasks.google.com/embed/?origin=https://calendar.google.com”

Note:  I created a separate directory for the “user-data-dir”, if you don’t and there is an existing running chrome session it will launch as a tab in that session